# How to parse « the greatest jobs president »

Tags: phrase-meaning, parts-of-speech

I can't parse the following sentence :

> « I will be the greatest jobs president that God ever created! »

My problem is the role of the word "jobs" in "the greatest jobs president". I just don't understand why it's there. Does it change the meaning of the phrase or what value does it add ?

Comment: He probably wants to say that his presidency will result in many new jobs being created in the economy.

Comment: @CowperKettle Are you sure we can create jobs in the **economy**?

Comment: @Cardinal - in the grammatic(al?) sense, not sure. In the semantic sense, why not?

Comment: @CowperKettle Nothing, Just curiosity. I was thinking to a country's economy. I wasn't sure the economy whether or not can mean a country's economy.

Comment: @CowperKettle It does not look like a very common phrase: https://www.google.com/#tbm=bks&q=%22create+jobs+in+the+economy%22

Comment: "Jobs president" is a noun phrase. The head word is "president" and the noun "jobs" is an attributive modifier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an attributive noun. It makes "president" more specific: it's talking about a president that has something to do with "jobs". In this case, that means a president that encourages or creates job opportunities, reducing unemployment.

Similarly, a "dog person" is someone that likes or is good with dogs.

Comment: When reading your answer I read the « dog person » analogy first and that made it clear immediately.

Comment: @YoungFrog: Glad I put that in, then!